Is a Baal Teshuva required to keep the surname of his non-Jewish father?
There are some Jews who are Halachically Jewish but come from mixed backgrounds. In such cases, the Jew may carry his father's surname.
Socially speaking, I can imagine such a situation causing problems for a Jew who is genuinely trying to meld into a community. Imagine a shidduch situation where someone is seeking a wife but their last name sends the message they aren't observant.
This leads to my question, is a Jew required to keep their non-Jewish father's last name?
It's a commandment that one needs to honor their father and mother. I can imagine the act of removing your father's last name from your identity would be seen as an extreme form of disrespect. You're essentially severing ties from them and ending their legacy in a sense.
That being said, if a Jew is genuinely trying to be observant and the name creates social barriers to full community absorption, is it wrong or sinful for a Jew to change their name to something more obviously Jewish? Maybe their Jewish mother's maiden name?

People change last names all the time.

I think you should ask a) is it part of the mitzva of kibbud av to keep one's father's last name, and b) is there a mitzva to honour one's non-Jewish father. If either of these is no, then this question would fall away

If a potential shidduch thinks that "Michael Friedman" was obviously raised observant [what if his mother wasn't Jewish and he just converted yesterday?], but "Michael Kennedy" was obviously not [what if his paternal great-grandfather was a convert and they've been observant for a hundred years?], with no other information whatsoever... they are jumping to a ton of a conclusions and probably not the best shidduch. So on a practical note -- trying to hide stuff only makes more complications in the long run ...

@shmosel While that's true, I'm asking if keeping your surname is considered a requirement as it could be deemed disrespectful to one's father to change it. Is a Jew more inclined to make a decision which better melds him into a Jewish community or is he more inclined to make a decision which honors his non-Jewish father.
I'm asking if this topic has ever come up or been discussed.
